# Функция не принимает переменную

Tags: javascript

Задача.
Напишите функцию `hello`, которая при вызове будет принимать переменную `name` и выводить строку на основе `name`, а в случае отсутствующего аргумента выводить «Привет, гость».

Вот мой код:

```
function hello() {
    //var name= "Василий";
    var name;
    alert("Привет, " + name);
    if (name === underfined)
    {
        alert=("Привет, гость");
    }
}
hello();
```

Вот что в результате получается: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу никак добиться правильного результата. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: убери `var name;` и поменяй `function hello() {` на `function hello(name) {`

Comment: ну и логично что сначала без проверки выполняется с _undefined_ и только потом проверка на него проходит

Comment: нужно создать функцию без параметров и создать потом var. Вот в этом и загвоздка у меня.

Comment: @АлінаШепель как сочетаются: "hello (), которая при вызове будет принимать переменную name" и "нужно создать функцию без параметров"?

Comment: @АлінаШепель, думаю вам стоит английский подучить. в слове `underfined` есть опечатка.

Comment: @Igor, `underfined` можно получить исключение `VM102:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: underfined is not defined`

Comment: @Igor неа, если пытаться использовать переменную до того как ей значение присвоится то будет исключение. а не сравнение с undefined

Comment: на тайском давайте уже комментировать, что вы как туристы..

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант с ES2015: [значение параметров по умолчанию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

```
function hello(name='Гость') {
  alert(`Привет, ${name}`);
}
```

Comment: Будущее – здесь!  А про сложности вроде необходимости установки бабелей-шмабелей скромно умолчим. )

Comment: 20155?​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @Qwertiy, fixed :-)

Comment: @Sergiks, конкретно эта фича не поддерживается только в ie и safari, думаю они скоро тоже подтянуться :) Кстати специально указал что это именно новый стандарт :):):)

Comment: @Grundy написали, что это стандарт, без подробностей. Как на печеньке мелким текстом указать «содержит E455, E666 и ГМО» – все ж знают, типа, что от этого можно ласты склеить в IE с Safari )

Comment: @Sergiks, там рядом, специально еще и ссылка проставлена с детальным описанием ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы функция приняла аргумент извне, он указывается в скобках при объявлении функции:

```
function hello(name) { }
```

Так внутри функции уже будет объявлена безо всяких `var` переменная `name`. Вызываете `hello("Ola")` – переменная `name` будет содержать строку "Ola". Вызовете без значения `hello()` – переменная `name` будет объявлена, но будет содержать специальное значение `undefined`.

Итого, как-то так:

```js
function hello(name) {

    // если name не передали, поприветствуем "гостя"
    if(name === undefined) name = "гость";

    alert("Привет, " + name);
}
hello();
```

Comment: Неа. `hello(void(0));`

Comment: выпендрёж засчитан )  Введите это значение через `<input>`, пжлст

Comment: Input тут не причем. В вопросе говорится об аргументах функции. По видимому, речь о типичной лабораторке. Так что если уж отвечать на такие вопросы, то с учетом всех тонкостей и подколов.

Comment: Тогда ещё подкол: `hello( {name:"Квазимодо"} )`, или функцию передать на досуге..

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, а я так и не понял прикола с `hello(void(0))` - `void(0)` же _undefined_ возвращает, и внутри проверка на _undefined_ и все отработает. В чем ошибка?

Comment: @Grundy видимо, DS хочет «Привет, void(0)!» : ) В условии пишут «в случае отсутствующего аргумента..»

Comment: @Grundy, `hello(void(0))` это _вызов с аргументом_. Значение аргумента в данном случае не должно иметь разницы

Answer (score 0):

```
function hello1(name) { // Пустая строка станет гостем
  alert("Привет, " + (name || "Гость"));
}

function hello2(name) { // Только null и undefined станут гостем
  alert("Привет, " + (name == null ? "Гость" : name));
}

function hello3(name) { // Только undefined станет гостем
  alert("Привет, " + (name === undefined ? "Гость" : name));
}

function hello4(name) { // Только вызов без аргументов покажет гостя
  alert("Привет, " + (arguments.length ? name : "Гость"));
}
```

Comment: Из четырех вариантов, условиям в точности отвечает только последние два.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, во-первых, я уже это уточнил сам. Во-вторых, последний вариант хуже третьего из-за того. А ещё он не оптимизируется браузером.

Comment: Третий вариант может провалить элементарный тест: `hello3(void(0))`. как бы ой

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, третий это какой? все которые не длину аргументов проверяют проходят

Comment: Дякую всім, але ось, що я хотіла. Прочитайте детально завдання. function hello() {
//var name ="Василій";
var name;
if(!name) name = "гість";
alert("Привіт, " + name);
}
hello();

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, а точно ли вызывающий функцию с явным указанием undefined на самом деле хочет увидеть undefined?

Comment: дякую всім за старання!

Comment: @Grundy, они как бы пронумерованы 1...4 ;)

Comment: @АлінаШепель, все-таки лучше по-русски  :):):)

Comment: @АлінаШепель, я прочитал. "При вызове будет принимать" - это именно то, что у меня написано. А твой вариант - это объявление переменной внутри функции.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ты же снова выполнил лабораторную работу **за** человека. А лабораторки предполагают точного следования условию. так что только четвертый вариант подходит.

Comment: @Grundy, хорошо;) будет сделано!

Comment: Ответ не объясняет, почему вариант топикстартера не будет работать.

Comment: @Risto, может это потому, что у ТС фарш с опечатками вместо нормального варианта? ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, я Вас поняла.

Comment: _"А лабораторки предполагают точного следования условию."_ Во-первых, с каких это пор? А во-вторых, это ж не сайт решения лабораторок, так что даже если так, это не мешает дать нормальный ответ.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev у ТСа эталонная ошибка при работе с функциями у начинающих. Чтобы ответ на данный вопрос был полезен другим участникам, он должен, в первую очередь, указать на ошибку и объяснить её.

Comment: @Risto, чтобы этот вопрос стал полезен сообществу, он должен быть, как минимум, приведен в порядок. А уже потом можно браться за подробное описание в ответах.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev второй раз за сегодня повторю: Низкое качество вопроса **не является** оправданием для низкого качества ответа на него. Считаете, что вопрос не стоит того, чтобы на него отвечать - **не отвечайте**, ваше право. А если отвечаете - делайте это **как следует**.